# How to correctly setup cron job notifications

Tags: cron

I'm trying to setup to receive notification everytime my cron job fails, but i'm not sure if I am doing it correctly. This is my current setup.

The second line, i'm trying to clean my csv file, while the third line, i want that clean file to be copied to google cloud storage. How do I receive a notification when any of the jobs fail?

```
MAILTO:myemail@gmail.com
*/1 * * * *  csvcut -x -e UTF-16 myfile.csv > newfile.csv
*/6 * * * *  gsutil mv -r newfile.csv gs://gcsbucket
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I noticed is `MAILTO:myemail@gmail.com`

To set the MAILTO variable you should use:

```
      MAILTO=username@domain.com
```

[Sending Email Alerts Through Cron](https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/sending-email-alerts-through-cron/)

Also your system should be able to send mails. Please check this related question on SO which describes how to configure your system.

[How do I set Cron to send emails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020965/how-do-i-set-cron-to-send-emails)

To get an email every time a cron job fails you should redirect all of your standard output to `/dev/null` or to some file and the STDERR messages will be emailed.

[Get email when a cron job fails](https://coderwall.com/p/nwqhxa/get-email-when-a-cron-job-fails)

Comment: i tried with this command and it didnt work for me, i didnt receive any email: ```MAILTO=hello@gmail.com

* * * * * gsutil cp test.txt gs://gcsbucket > /dev/null```